# Postgresql поиск первой строки, соответствующей запросу

Tags: postgresql

Есть запрос по условию. Как получить первую попавшуюся запись, соответствующую условию запроса не обходя всю базу дальше?

Comment: Используйте limit https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgrespro/9.5/queries-limit  А будет ли оно обходить всю таблицу или нет - это уже по желанию оптимизатора

Comment: поробуйте Limit 1

Comment: *Как получить первую попавшуюся запись* Именно получить запись? тогда `LIMIT 1`. Или просто убедиться, что такая запись существует? тогда `EXISTS`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно ограничить размер выдачи. Используйте [LIMIT](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#SQL-LIMIT). Например:

```
SELECT * FROM users LIMIT 1;
```